# Why do Unicode characters prevent the [[:punct:]] character class from matching "+" in subsequent regexp matches in Ruby 2.4?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

I came across a strange bug in Ruby. In Ruby 2.4.2, matching against a string containing a Unicode character caused subsequent matches to fail.

Here's my attempt to isolate the bug:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
["0.", "0+", "é", "0.", "0+"].each do |phrase|
  p phrase[/[[:digit:]][[:punct:]]/]
end
```

Here's the output for various Ruby versions:

```
2.3.5
"0."
nil
nil
"0."
nil

2.4.2
"0."
"0+"
nil
"0."
nil

2.5.0
"0."
"0+"
nil
"0."
"0+"
```

In 2.3.5, `0+` is missed altogether, apparently because `+` isn't considered punctuation. In 2.5.0, both `0.` and `0+` are matched.

In 2.4.2, though, the behavior is baffling: Why does matching against a string containing a Unicode character interfere with subsequent regex matches? Presumably this is a bug, but I couldn't find any information about how it was caused or how to work around it.

Comment: BTW, the example can be shortened to `p %w[+ é +].grep(/[[:punct:]]/)` which returns `["+"]` instead of `["+", "+"]` in 2.4.2

Comment: Interestingly enough, `%w[+ µ +].each { |s| p s[/\p{Punct}/] }` seems to work fine (in 2.4.1) whereas `%w[+ µ +].each { |s| p s[/[[:punct:]]/] }` does not.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/issues/42

Comment: I created a bug report: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14488